# networkx installed but cannot import: No module named 'networkx'

Tags: python, networkx

I installed networkx with `pip` using this command:

```
[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ pip install networkx
```

Just to show you, by using `pip install networkx`, it says it is already installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.6.2)
```

However, when I try to import networkx into python

```
import networkx as nx
```

I get this message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'
```

In addition, also by trying with ([pytest networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/install.html))

```
[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ pytest networkx
```

I get the error `file not found: networkx`, as shown here below:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-3.8.0, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: /home/JohnRambo, inifile:
plugins: remotedata-0.3.0, openfiles-0.3.0, doctestplus-0.1.3, arraydiff-0.2

========================= no tests ran in 0.01 seconds =========================
ERROR: file not found: networkx
```

**Any idea on how to fix it?**

Additional information, if it can be useful:

```
[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ python -V
Python 3.7.7

[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ python3 -V 
Python 3.7.7

[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ pip --version 
pip 21.1.3 from /home/JohnRambo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7) 

[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ pip3 --version 
pip 21.1.3 from /home/JohnRambo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which python 
~/anaconda3/bin/python 

[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which python3 
~/anaconda3/bin/python3 

[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which pip 
~/anaconda3/bin/pip 

[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which pip3 
~/anaconda3/bin/pip3

[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which pytest 
~/anaconda3/bin/pytest
```

Comment: did you check that `pip` belongs to the same environment of `python`? in case use `which pip` and `which python` to test it

Comment: Thanks @Andrea! It looks like they belong to the same env: 

`[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which python
~/anaconda3/bin/python`
`[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which python3
~/anaconda3/bin/python3`
`[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which pip
~/anaconda3/bin/pip`
`[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ which pip3
~/anaconda3/bin/pip3`

Comment: Hi please add additional information in the original post as code snippets, not as comments. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try `pip3 install networkx==1.11`

Comment: thanks @Lakshana Ravishankar!

Answer (score 1):

while in a virtual env, do the command `pipenv install networkx` because for some reason `pip install` sometimes doesn't recognize pipenv commands.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sort of answer, but I do not think it is really good...

By following the [NoModuleNamed guide](https://nomodulenamed.com/a/I-have-installed-the-package-using-pip), I first checked the `sys.executable` in python

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

which gave this:

```
/bin/python3
```

Then, I tried to install networkx there, by using the instructions given both in the [NoModuleNamed guide](https://nomodulenamed.com/a/I-have-installed-the-package-using-pip) and in [installation guide of networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/install.html):

```
[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ /bin/python3 -m pip install networkx[default]
```

Just for information, I got this (after installation):

```
Requirement already satisfied: networkx[default] in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.5.1)
WARNING: networkx 2.5.1 does not provide the extra 'default'
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<5,>=4.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from networkx[default]) (4.4.2)
```

Now, the command `import networkx` inside python does not give me any error, but

1. if I check the networkx installation from Terminal `[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ pytest networkx`, I still get `ERROR: file not found: networkx`, and
2. that version of networkx is the `2.5.1` while I would like the `2.6` one.

Once I try to upgrade networkx through the command

```
[JohnRambo@Machine ~]$ /bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade networkx[default]
```

I get this message:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: networkx[default] in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.5.1)
WARNING: networkx 2.5.1 does not provide the extra 'default'
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<5,>=4.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from networkx[default]) (4.4.2)
```

**Is it still OK to install within `/bin/python3` or it is not a correct practice?**

**How can I upgrade my networkx?**